# Physical model described by modify Helmholtz equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, lagrangian-formalism

The wave equation $\partial_t^2u=c\Delta u$ is usually handled through a time-harmonic ansatz, which reduces it to Helmholtz equation $\Delta u+\omega^2u=0$.

I'm interested in the following modified Helmholtz equation
$$
\Delta u + \omega^2u+\nabla_v u  = 0\tag{1}
$$
where $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\nabla_v$ is the corresponding directional derivative.

**My question:** To which physical system does this equation belong to?

*My thinking:* This reminds me to a damped wave equation ($\partial_t^2u-\partial_tu=c\Delta u$), but with damping happening in space in direction $v$. I can't however think to a physical system that would behave like this and justify why we would get $(1)$ as its governing equation.

---

Update:
(1) is the time harmonic equation derived from the following Lagrangian:

$$
L(x,t,u,u_x,u_t) = e^x\left(\frac{1}{2}(u_t)^2-\frac{1}{2}(u_x)^2\right)
$$